# Can capture groups be used like perl?

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to determine how many `#` characters are at the beginning of a line.

In perl, I can so something like this:

```
$match =~ m/^(#+)[^#])/;
$length = length $1;
```

Trying to do something similar in vim:

```
getline(a:lnum) =~ '\v^(#+)[^#]'
let length = strlen \1
```

I believe the `\v` allows me to write a regex like perl, correct?

I'm just not sure if I can do capturing like I'm doing here or not.

Comment: `\v` does *not* mean perl regex; it means very-magic vim regex. In practice you can do all the same things, but the syntaxes differ at points. Check the help for that. Then check the help for `match()`, `substitute()`, and `submatch()`

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with match, but was asking specifically about using capture groups like in perl.

Comment: Have you read `:h submatch()` ? That should give you enough to experiment and self-answer.

Comment: Not yet. But I will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, VimScript is not like Perl. It's basically a separate programming language and while it look like to support perl like regexes (`\v`), those are not really perl like, since Vim supports different features for matching (see also [:h perl-patterns](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns)).

This means, captured groups are basically only valid within a `substitute()` function (or within a `:s` command).

To get the number of `#` at the start of the line, you can however use this:

```
:echo strlen(matchstr(getline('.'), '^#\+'))
```

(using `'.'` for the cursor line).

Answer (score 2):

@ChristanBrabandt typed [his answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19768/343) faster than me, so I won't repeat the information he's already given, or the simpler solution he supplied to your example problem.

However, you suggested in a comment that solving this problem isn't your main goal, and that you actually want to know [specifically whether it's possible to use capture groups like in Perl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19767/can-capture-groups-be-used-like-perl/19769#comment34500_19767).

I'll therefore add the addendum that Vim does have a close analogue to how you describe Perl's capture groups: the `matchlist()` function. You can use this to write Vimscript that more closely mirrors your Perl code:

```
let groups = matchlist(getline(a:lnum), '\v^(#+)[^#]')
let length = empty(groups) ? 0 : len(groups[1])
```